# How To Make Larger Background Images Repeat, Regardless Of Browser Size?

Tags: image, web, background, repeat

I have a 512x512 image I'd like to use as a pattern in which I would like to tile. I can get it to only repeat-x because the image is pretty large and will not repeat-y, is there a specific set of code I should be using like position: something or overflow: something.

Thank you very much,
Aaron

Comment: It doesn't actually sound like there's a problem. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: Are you using CSS? XAML? Plain HTML? Something else entirely?

Comment: Retagged from 'design' to 'web-design'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try a combination of these

```
repeat-x;
repeat-y;
repeat;
background-position:center;
background-position:left top;
background-position:left center;
background-position:left bottom;
background-position:right top;
background-position:right center;
background-position:right bottom;
background-position:center top;
background-position:center center;
background-position:50% 50%;
background-position:10px 200px;
background-position:center bottom
```